# How to preserve file permissions with cmake "install directory" directive?

Tags: directory, installation, cmake, file-permissions, preserve

***Prolog**: I'm an idiot for missing this in the documentation*

cmake-2.8.10.2

How do you make cmake preserve the original file permissions when installing a directory?  For the project at hand, I'd like it to essentially copy some directories from my source tree to the install tree.  To wit:

```
install(
  DIRECTORY config runp
  DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}
  PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
  PATTERN ".git" EXCLUDE
  PATTERN "start_collection.snl" EXCLUDE
)
```

All works as expected -- except that executable scripts are getting copied in with incorrect file permissions.  In fact, **none** of the original file permissions are preserved.   Globally setting permissions using FILE_PERMISSIONS and DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS is something I do not want to do, and frankly, would be a hack in this context.

In the shell-scripting world, I'd do something simple like this:

```
for i in config runp ; do
  tar cf - $i | tar -C $CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX -xf -
done
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Documentation suggests using `USE_SOURCE_PERMISSIONS` when calling `install()`:

```
install(
  DIRECTORY config runp
  DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}
  USE_SOURCE_PERMISSIONS
  PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
  PATTERN ".git" EXCLUDE
  PATTERN "start_collection.snl" EXCLUDE
)
```

Alternatively, you can use `install(PROGRAMS` signature of this command. [See docs](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command:install) for more info.

Comment: Well, I'm an idiot.  I somehow glossed right over that option in the documentation.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Thanks; just wanted to mention that `USE_SOURCE_PERMISSIONS` only works with `install(DIRECTORY)`. It wasn't immediately obvious from the answer.